# R: Equivalencia entre for y apply

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy intentando implementar el contraste **T de Wilcoxon** por mi cuenta para comparar sus resultados con los que proporciona la función interna que incorpora el propio R.

Aún no tengo claro cómo, de momento estoy haciendo pruebas con un bucle `for` y querría encontrar su equivalencia "elegante" en forma de función de la familia `apply`.

Sería para una única muestra y se quiere contrastar si la mediana es 5.

```
me0 = 5
muestra = c(4, 5, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 6)
```

Obtengo las diferencias entre los elementos de la muestra y la mediana hipotética:

```
diferencias = muestra - me0
```

Resultado:

```
 [1] -1  0  1  0 -2 -1 -3  2  1  0 -1 -2  3  3  4 -1  1  2 -3  0  1
```

De cara a determinar los rangos, aunque esta solución no me convence mucho porque pierdo información que tendría que recuperar posteriormente, elimino los ceros, obtengo el valor absoluto de las diferencias y ordeno la secuencia de menor a mayor:

```
absolutas = sort(abs(diferencias[diferencias != 0]))
```

Resultado:

```
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4
```

Ahora determino qué elementos diferentes hay:

```
niveles = as.numeric(levels(factor(absolutas)))
```

Resultado:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Y mediante un bucle, obtengo los rangos:

```
rangos = c()

for(nivel in niveles)
{
  rangos = c(rangos, mean(which(absolutas == nivel)))
}
```

Resultado:

```
[1]  4.5 10.5 14.5 17.0
```

Que es lo esperable.

Y la pregunta es cómo mejorar la sintaxis del bucle `for` utilizando alguna función de la familia `apply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediante `sapply()` puedes obtener directamente el vector que buscas:

```
sapply(niveles, FUN = function(x) mean(which(absolutas == x)))
```

Por otro lado, vale la pena comentar, que reemplazar un `for()` por una de las  `*apply()` es más una cuestión de gustos o de hacer un código más compacto y consistente con la mecánica tradicional de R, pero no hay gran impacto a nivel performance.

Comment: Sí, se trataba sobre todo de una cuestión de estilo. Gracias, Patricio.